# adiabatic isochoric phase transition

Tags: thermodynamics

Assume that a first order transition occurs in an adiabatically isolated system at constant volume without external work. Would there be a change in entropy?

Comment: Can you give an example of how such a change could occur?  Can you give a specific example of the initial and final thermodynamic equilibrium states of such a system?

Answer (score 1):

If the system was in equilibrium to begin with, then since its closed adiabatic and isochoric, its $U,V,N,$ remain constant, and so its thermodynamic state is unchanged, which means its entropy remains unchanged. If phase change did occur, then it could not have been in an equilibrium state to begin with, so at least within classical thermodynamics, you cannot assign entropy to the initial state. Of course the final equilibrium state would have a well defined value for entropy, but you cannot now speak of change in entropy.